# Force vertical scrollbar to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a chat window, and I want to always see bottom of this chat. I tried two ways, both of them are here: http://jsfiddle.net/9hMXL/518/ and none of it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, since SO requires me to put some code here, here is html of the page:

```
<div id="contt"  class="cont">
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Hi there! Nice scrollbars, aren't they?</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#contt` doesn't have the scrollbar.  `window` does.

```
$(window).scrollTop(400);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9hMXL/519/

Comment: This works great I just changed the 400 to 2500 because it wasn't going all the way to the bottom. Do you know of a way I can add some effects with CSS so that it doesn't jump the camera so fast? I want it to slowly glide to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

$(window).scrollTop(window.height)

Or if you're using an internal frame, use it in place of window.